# How to reduce size of an Android DB

Tags: android, database, sqlite, size

I have an app with an internal DB, this DB is compressed and dumped in a server, when the user synk the app. Now the DB is too big for this operation.

- I try to reduce file size with SQLite (using **VACUUM**).
- I delete rows of the tables

But the size is passed from 278MB to 250MB.

How can reduce the file size?

I don't find any solution on web.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Reduce the amount of data you're storing in the database.

Comment: Do the VACUUM *after* deleting.

Comment: Hi at all,
I tried to delete 4000 rows in a table (out of a total of 10,000 rows) and all the rows in which the corresponding key was present. But released only 28MB no more..